# In fiction, can I write about Downing College, Cambridge?

Tags: fiction, naming, setting

I have included, in my fictional book, several mentions about Downing College, Cambridge. Now they have a fete on their lawns. Two Russians are killed there during the fete. No mention of staff involved, all the rest is nice stuff.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Geoff.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  Your question is one that has been asked before in broader ways and is really a matter of opinion.  The answer is "sure."

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can write about a place without getting into trouble about it. Look at all the authors who have done this before: Ian Fleming, J.K. Rowling, Nick Hornby.